# python pandas - flight arrival and departure time on separate row - to be matched and joined to same row then draw gantt chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, gantt-chart

Say I have a dataframe like this (notebook text version follows the image):

A is Arrival Flight (landing), D is Departure flight (take off).
Carrier and FltReg together is a single aircraft.. that arrives and departs an airport, and it will come back again to same airport.. after few hours or days.
Acft is the type of aircraft.

The arrivals and departures need to be matched so that the resulting dataframe can be used for calculations and drawing gantt chart (start time i.e. arrival time and end time i.e. departure time... the time the flight is on the ground.)

*the data will normally will continue for 7 days flight schedules and many more carriers.. about 3000 rows for 7 days... coming from sql server database*

[image]

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

dfstr = StringIO(u"""
ID;Car;FltNo;Acft;FltReg;E_FltType;Rtg;STADDtTm;ArrDep
0;EK;376;77W;A6ECI;T/A;DXB-BKK-DXB;03/05/2017 12:50;A
1;EK;377;77W;A6ECI;T/A;DXB-BKK-DXB;03/05/2017 15:40;D
2;EK;384;380;A6EDL;T/S;DXB-BKK-HKG;02/05/2017 12:15;A
3;EK;384;380;A6EDL;T/S;DXB-BKK-HKG;02/05/2017 14:00;D
4;EK;385;380;A6EDL;T/A;HKG-BKK-DXB;02/05/2017 23:45;A
5;EK;385;380;A6EDL;T/A;HKG-BKK-DXB;03/05/2017 01:15;D
54;VZ;920;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-HPH;01/05/2017 11:15;D
55;VZ;921;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;HPH-BKK;01/05/2017 15:25;A
56;VZ;602;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-CNX;01/05/2017 16:35;D
57;VZ;603;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;CNX-BKK;01/05/2017 19:45;A
58;VZ;602;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-CNX;02/05/2017 11:15;D
59;VZ;603;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;CNX-BKK;02/05/2017 14:25;A
60;VZ;820;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-HKT;03/05/2017 07:05;D
61;VZ;821;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;HKT-BKK;03/05/2017 15:45;A
62;VZ;828;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-HKT;03/05/2017 18:20;D
63;VZ;829;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;HKT-BKK;03/05/2017 21:50;A
64;VZ;600;320;HSVKB;DEP ONLY;BKK-CNX;01/05/2017 06:10;D
65;VZ;601;320;HSVKB;ARR ONLY;CNX-BKK;01/05/2017 09:20;A
66;VZ;606;320;HSVKB;DEP ONLY;BKK-CNX;01/05/2017 09:50;D
67;VZ;607;320;HSVKB;ARR ONLY;CNX-BKK;01/05/2017 13:00;A

""")
df = pd.read_csv(dfstr, sep=";", index_col='ID')
df
```

**Question 1: How to conver the above dataframe to below.**

I want this converted to same rows if the Car and FltReg is same.. for e.g. ID 0, EK376 A6ECI Arrival at 03May 12:50 and departs as ID 1, EK377 A6ECI at 03May 15:40... similarly for ID2 and 3, ID4 and 5... these are 3 different aircrafts as highlighted in BOLD. many other flights in between... then Next comes, ID54 which is a VZ Carrier with Aircraft Reg HSKVA... and it departs first, so it should be on its own row... then it arrives ID55 and departs as ID56, and arrives again as ID57 and departs as ID58.

Here is how the resulting dataframe should look like:[image]

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

dfstr = StringIO(u"""
IDArr;Car;FltNo;Acft;FltReg;E_FltType;Rtg;STADDtTm;ArrDep;IDDep;Car;FltNo;Acft;FltReg;E_FltType;Rtg;STADDtTm;ArrDep
0;EK;376;77W;A6ECI;T/A;DXB-BKK-DXB;03/05/2017 12:50;A;1;EK;377;77W;A6ECI;T/A;DXB-BKK-DXB;03/05/2017 15:40;D
2;EK;384;380;A6EDL;T/S;DXB-BKK-HKG;02/05/2017 12:15;A;3;EK;384;380;A6EDL;T/S;DXB-BKK-HKG;02/05/2017 14:00;D
4;EK;385;380;A6EDL;T/A;HKG-BKK-DXB;02/05/2017 23:45;A;5;EK;385;380;A6EDL;T/A;HKG-BKK-DXB;03/05/2017 01:15;D
;;;;;;;;;54;VZ;920;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-HPH;01/05/2017 11:15;D
55;VZ;921;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;HPH-BKK;01/05/2017 15:25;A;56;VZ;602;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-CNX;01/05/2017 16:35;D
57;VZ;603;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;CNX-BKK;01/05/2017 19:45;A;58;VZ;602;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-CNX;02/05/2017 11:15;D
59;VZ;603;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;CNX-BKK;02/05/2017 14:25;A;60;VZ;820;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-HKT;03/05/2017 07:05;D
61;VZ;821;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;HKT-BKK;03/05/2017 15:45;A;62;VZ;828;320;HSVKA;DEP ONLY;BKK-HKT;03/05/2017 18:20;D
63;VZ;829;320;HSVKA;ARR ONLY;HKT-BKK;03/05/2017 21:50;A;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;64;VZ;600;320;HSVKB;DEP ONLY;BKK-CNX;01/05/2017 06:10;D
65;VZ;601;320;HSVKB;ARR ONLY;CNX-BKK;01/05/2017 09:20;A;66;VZ;606;320;HSVKB;DEP ONLY;BKK-CNX;01/05/2017 09:50;D
67;VZ;607;320;HSVKB;ARR ONLY;CNX-BKK;01/05/2017 13:00;A;;;;;;;;;

""")
df2 = pd.read_csv(dfstr, sep=";")
df2
```

As you can see... we can see ID0 and ID1 is matched in same row... thus it is easier to see how long the flight is on the ground (that is in the airport)... from 12:50 to 15:40 (2 hour 50 mins)... and so on for the rest of the flights.

**Question 2: Make Gantt chart with above resulting data frame**

This resulting dataframe will then be used for generating Gantt Charts.

that is example Aircraft: HSKVA (VZ Flight) will have its own row... with 11:15 departure first (gantt drawn from 10:15 (1hr before departure as there is no arrival) to 11:15. then gantt drawn in same row for 15:25 to 16:35, 19:45 to 11:15 next day, 14:25 to 07:05, 15:45 to 18:20, 21:50 to 22:50 (one hour after flight arrival as there isno departure). **broken_barh of matplotlib comes to mind**

HSKVB will have its own row for the gantt... and so on.

Each Carrier/Aircraft Reg on its own row for the visual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1**

One quick change to your setup is that I didn't set `ID` as the `index_col` because I want to use its value quickly in a `groupby().shift`. So starting from that modified `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(dfstr, sep=";")
cols = df.columns.values.tolist()
```

A big part of the solution is making sure the df is ordered by `Car`, `FltReg`, and `STADDtTm` (because the first two are the unique identifiers, and the last is the main sort value).

```
sort_cols = ['Car', 'FltReg', 'STADDtTm']
df.sort_values(by=sort_cols, inplace=True)
```

So now we're at the main part of the logic. I'm going to separate df into arrivals and departures, and the way the two are going to be joined is by a **shifted ID**. That is, for any (`Car`, `FltReg`) partition, I know to pair a given 'A' row with the 'D' row immediately after it. So again, this is why we need sorted (and complete) data.

Let's generate that shifted ID:

```
# sort_cols[:2] is `Car` and `FltReg` together
df['NextID'] = df.groupby(sort_cols[:2])['ID'].shift(1)
```

Now using an 'A'-filtered df and a 'D'-filtered df, I am going to full-outer-join them together. Arrivals (left dataset) are keyed by the original `ID`, and departures (right dataset) are keyed by the `NextID` we just made.

```
df_display = df[df['ArrDep'] == 'A'] \
                 .merge(df[df['ArrDep'] == 'D'],
                       how='outer',
                       left_on='ID',
                       right_on='NextID',
                       suffixes=('1', '2'))
```

Note that the columns will now be suffixed with `1` (left) and `2` (right).

At this point, this new dataframe `df_display` has all the rows it needs, but it doesn't have the nice sort in your final display. To accomplish this, you need the `sort_cols` list again, but *coalesced* versions of each column that put the respective left and right versions together. For example, `Car1` and `Car2` have to be coalesced together, so that you can sort **all rows** by the combined version.

pandas' `combine_first` is like coalesce.

```
# purely for sorting the final display
for c in sort_cols: 
    df_display['sort_' + c] = df_display[c + '1'] \
                                  .combine_first(df_display[c + '2'])
    # for example, Car1 and Car2 have now been coalesced into sort_Car

df_display.sort_values(by=['sort_{}'.format(c) for c in sort_cols], inplace=True)
```

We're almost done. Now `df_display` has extraneous columns that we don't need. We can select only the columns we want—basically, two copies of the original column list `cols`.

```
df_display = df_display[['{}1'.format(c) for c in cols] + ['{}2'.format(c) for c in cols]]
df_display.to_csv('output.csv', index=None)
```

I checked (in a csv export so that we could see the wide dataset) that this matches your sample.

[image: output]

**Question 2**

Okay, so if you play around with the code at https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_barh.html, you can see how `broken_barh` operates. This is important, as we have to make the data fit this structure to be able to use it. `broken_barh`'s first argument is a list of tuples to plot, and each tuple is a (start time, duration).

For matplotlib, the start time has to be in its special date format. So we have to convert pandas datetimes using `matplotlib.dates.date2num`. Finally, the duration seems like it's in day units.

Thus, if HSVKA arrives at 2017-05-01 15:25:00 and is on the ground for 70 minutes, then `broken_barh` needs to plot the tuple `(mdates.date2num(Timestamp('2017-05-03 15:25:00')), 70 minutes in day units or 0.04861)`.

So the first step is getting `df_display` from **Question 1** in this format. We only need to focus on the four columns `'Car1', 'FltReg1', 'STADDtTm1', 'STADDtTm2'` now.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn # optional ... I like the look

print(df_display[['Car1', 'FltReg1', 'STADDtTm1', 'STADDtTm2']])
```

which looks like

```
   Car1 FltReg1         STADDtTm1         STADDtTm2
0    EK   A6ECI  03/05/2017 12:50  03/05/2017 15:40
1    EK   A6EDL  02/05/2017 12:15  02/05/2017 14:00
2    EK   A6EDL  02/05/2017 23:45  03/05/2017 01:15
10  NaN     NaN               NaN  01/05/2017 11:15
3    VZ   HSVKA  01/05/2017 15:25  01/05/2017 16:35
4    VZ   HSVKA  01/05/2017 19:45  02/05/2017 11:15
5    VZ   HSVKA  02/05/2017 14:25  03/05/2017 07:05
6    VZ   HSVKA  03/05/2017 15:45  03/05/2017 18:20
7    VZ   HSVKA  03/05/2017 21:50               NaN
11  NaN     NaN               NaN  01/05/2017 06:10
8    VZ   HSVKB  01/05/2017 09:20  01/05/2017 09:50
9    VZ   HSVKB  01/05/2017 13:00               NaN
```

There are `NaN`s when an arrival or departure is missing. Imputing these is fairly straightforward. I noticed in your write-up that you wanted one-hour buffers on either side when something is missing. So here's all of that straightforward wrangling:

```
df_gantt = df_display.copy()

# Convert to pandas timestamps for date arithmetic
df_gantt['STADDtTm1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_gantt['STADDtTm1'],
                                       format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df_gantt['STADDtTm2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_gantt['STADDtTm2'],
                                       format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

# Impute identifiers
df_gantt['Car'] = df_gantt['Car1'].combine_first(df_gantt['Car2'])
df_gantt['FltReg'] = df_gantt['FltReg1'].combine_first(df_gantt['FltReg2'])

# Also just gonna combine Car and FltReg
# into a single column for simplicty
df_gantt['Car_FltReg'] = df_gantt['Car'] + ': ' +  df_gantt['FltReg']

# Impute hour gaps
df_gantt['STADDtTm1'] = df_gantt['STADDtTm1'] \
                            .fillna(df_gantt['STADDtTm2'] - pd.Timedelta('1 hour'))
df_gantt['STADDtTm2'] = df_gantt['STADDtTm2'] \
                            .fillna(df_gantt['STADDtTm1'] + pd.Timedelta('1 hour'))

# Date diff in day units
df_gantt['DayDiff'] = (df_gantt['STADDtTm2'] - df_gantt['STADDtTm1']).dt.seconds \
                          / 60 / 60 / 24

# matplotlib numeric date format
df_gantt['STADDtTm1'] = df_gantt['STADDtTm1'].apply(mdates.date2num)
df_gantt['STADDtTm2'] = df_gantt['STADDtTm2'].apply(mdates.date2num)

df_gantt = df_gantt[['Car_FltReg', 'STADDtTm1', 'STADDtTm2', 'DayDiff']]
print(df_gantt)
```

which now looks like

```
   Car_FltReg      STADDtTm1      STADDtTm2   DayDiff
0   EK: A6ECI  736452.534722  736452.652778  0.118056
1   EK: A6EDL  736451.510417  736451.583333  0.072917
2   EK: A6EDL  736451.989583  736452.052083  0.062500
10  VZ: HSVKA  736450.427083  736450.468750  0.041667
3   VZ: HSVKA  736450.642361  736450.690972  0.048611
4   VZ: HSVKA  736450.822917  736451.468750  0.645833
5   VZ: HSVKA  736451.600694  736452.295139  0.694444
6   VZ: HSVKA  736452.656250  736452.763889  0.107639
7   VZ: HSVKA  736452.909722  736452.951389  0.041667
11  VZ: HSVKB  736450.215278  736450.256944  0.041667
8   VZ: HSVKB  736450.388889  736450.409722  0.020833
9   VZ: HSVKB  736450.541667  736450.583333  0.041667
```

Now make a dict where each key is a unique `Car_FltReg` and each value is a list of tuples (as described earlier) that can be fed into `broken_barh`.

```
dict_gantt = df_gantt.groupby('Car_FltReg')['STADDtTm1', 'DayDiff'] \
                 .apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['STADDtTm1'].tolist(),
                                           x['DayDiff'].tolist()))) \
                 .to_dict()
```

So `dict_gantt` looks like

```
{'EK: A6ECI': [(736452.5347222222, 0.11805555555555557)],
 'EK: A6EDL': [(736451.5104166666, 0.07291666666666667),
               (736451.9895833334, 0.0625)],
 'VZ: HSVKA': [(736450.4270833334, 0.041666666666666664),
               (736450.6423611111, 0.04861111111111111),
               (736450.8229166666, 0.6458333333333334),
               (736451.6006944445, 0.6944444444444445),
               (736452.65625, 0.1076388888888889),
               (736452.9097222222, 0.041666666666666664)],
 'VZ: HSVKB': [(736450.2152777778, 0.041666666666666664),
               (736450.3888888889, 0.020833333333333332),
               (736450.5416666666, 0.041666666666666664)]}
```

Perfect for `broken_barh`. And now it's all the matplotlib craziness. After the core logic to prepare for `broken_barh` stuff, everything else is just the painstaking tick formatting, etc. If you've customized something in matplotlib, this stuff should be familiar—I won't explain much of it.

```
FltReg_list = sorted(dict_gantt, reverse=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

start_datetime = df_gantt['STADDtTm1'].min()
end_datetime = df_gantt['STADDtTm2'].max()

# parameters for yticks, etc.
# you might have to play around
# with the different parts to modify
n = len(FltReg_list)
bar_size = 9

for i, bar in enumerate(FltReg_list):
    ax.broken_barh(dict_gantt[bar],          # data
                   (10 * (i + 1), bar_size), # (y position, bar size)
                   alpha=0.75,
                   edgecolor='k',
                   linewidth=1.2)

# I got date formatting ideas from
# https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html
ax.set_xlim(start_datetime, end_datetime)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0, 24, 6)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d %H:%M'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0, 24, 1)))
# omitting minor labels ...

plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='w', linestyle='dotted')

ax.set_yticks([5 + 10 * n for n in range(1, n + 1)])
ax.set_ylim(5, 5 + 10 * (n + 1))
ax.set_yticklabels(FltReg_list)

ax.set_title('Time on Ground')
ax.set_ylabel('Carrier: Registration')

plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('gantt.png', dpi=200)
```

Here's the final output.

[image: gantt]